# Common Lisp method specialized on symbol - can't use in other packages, can't export?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, symbols, clos, practical-common-lisp

I've been working through *Practical Common Lisp*'s [binary parser project](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/practical-parsing-binary-files.html), and attempted to split the generics (class and macro definitions) and specifics (specific types and method implementations) into different packages. As such, I have the following code:

In packages.lisp:

```
(defpackage :binparse
  (:use :cl)
  (:export :read-value :write-value :read-object :write-object
           :current-binary-object :parent-of-type :define-binary-class
           :define-tagged-binary-class :define-binary-type))

(defpackage :primitives
  (:use :cl :binparse))
```

In binparse.lisp:

```
(defgeneric read-value (type stream &key)
  (:documentation "Read a value of the given type from the stream."))

(defgeneric write-value (type stream value &key)
  (:documentation "Write the value of the given type to the stream."))

(defmacro define-binary-type (name (&rest args) &body spec) ...) ; calls defmethod for read-value and write-value, specialized on (type (eql ,name))
```

In primitives.lisp:

```
(define-binary-type u1 () ...) ; defines reader and writer spec for 1-byte unsigned int, specialized on (type (eql 'u1))
```

I have been unable to determine how to properly export the method implementations from `primitives`. If I *don't* do any exports beyond what's defined in `packages` above, then I can do the following:

```
CL-USER> (binparse:read-value primitives::'u1 *testfile*) ; succeeds
CL-USER> (binparse:read-value primitives::u1 *testfile*) ; fails, unbound variable U1
CL-USER> (binparse:read-value 'u1 *testfile*); fails, class-not-found u1
PRIMITIVES> (read-value 'u1 *testfile*) ; succeeds
```

However, I can't figure out how to export `'u1` (or other symbols used as method specifiers) from `primitives` to avoid the double-colon or potentially allow importing into other packages. Including `(:export :u1)` in the `defpackage` doesn't work. Nor does calling `(export 'u1)` while already in `primitives`. And single-colon, unlike double-colon, doesn't allow the `::'u1` that worked originally.

This seems like a fairly normal thing to want to do to expand on the project from *PCL*, defining the basic binary-parser code in a package to be used elsewhere for specific extensions, but I can't figure out how to do it and haven't found anyone else asking about it.

Comment: unqualified U1 in CL-USER might not be the same symbol as PRIMITIVES::U1, try doing (describe 'u1) in CL-USER to see what its package is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out: If I `(:export #:u1)` in `packages.lisp`, I can get the correct specialization of the method using `(binparse:read-value 'primitives:u1 *testfile*)`. So, the quote goes *before* the package-name part of the symbol.